# Java program JButton freezes program after action, need multiple presses

Tags: java, swing, concurrency, jbutton

I am designing a program that accepts stock ticker symbols and number of shares from the user and I want it to add the information to an ArrayList and once they are done giving input to have it print the list to a text area. I had a general idea of how I wanted this to work coded out, but whenever I would push the button the program would freeze. Also, is there a way to have it print out everything in the arraylist? I have it setup as a for loop which just sets it as the last entered string.

```
private void GoButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          


    String ts1 = tickerSymbol1.getText();

    int s1 = Integer.parseInt(shares1.getText());

    String site = "http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=%22%20"+ts1+"%20+%20%22&f=sl1d1t1c1ohgv&e=.csv";
    try {
        URL stockURL = new URL(site);
        URLConnection data = stockURL.openConnection();
        Scanner input = new Scanner(data.getInputStream());

        if (input.hasNext())

        while (input.hasNextLine())
        {
            String line = input.nextLine();
            String[] stockinfo = line.split(",(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)");
            total1.setText(stockinfo[1]);


        }
    } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex);
    } 

}                                                                             

private void AddActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                    
    ArrayList<String> stocks = new ArrayList<String>();
    String input = tickerSymbol1.getText();
    do { 
        stocks.add(input);
    }while (input.equalsIgnoreCase("quit"));


            for (int i=0;i<stocks.size();i++)
            {
                jTextArea1.setText(stocks.get(i));
            }    
}
```

Comment: You're blocking the Swing event thread with long-running code, freezing your GUI. All long-running code should be called in a background thread, and all Swing calls should be called on the Swing event thread. A SwingWorker could work well for this. Please have a look at [Lesson: Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/)
 for more on this.

Comment: Thank you, I'll be sure to read up on that!